# Commenting an image util module gm

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, comments, gm

I'm trying to comment on an image using the `gm` module, but it only creates the same image I used without the comment.

**Code in Context**

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('api/routes/image1.jpg')
    .comment(['Text Example'])
    .write('api/routes/image2.png', 
     function(e) {
         console.log(e||'done');
     });
```

Comment: Are you expecting the text to be on the image itself? Because that's not what [comment](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-comment) is for. If so, you need to use `drawText`.

Comment: You alrigth. Thanks @BenFortune. Taking the gm documentation, you know some other stuff I can study this module?

Comment: The GraphicsMagick documentation is really good, `gm` is just a wrapper around it.

Comment: Thanks @BenFortune. More a question. I want create a white bar in bottom the image.  I thought I'd do a append a white image, but the image can has very with and heigth different, so that is not work. Do you know how I could create a bar in bottom the image with any size ?